# how to select Non-repetitive records from more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my database I have 4 tables that are related, and I want to select non-repetitive records, but I don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT
    UserID = dbo.tblUsers.id
    ,dbo.tblUsers.nickname
    ,dbo.tblUsers.avatarPic
    ,dbo.tblUsers.userRate
    ,dbo.tblUsers.workedProjects
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.userVotes
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesCount
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesPoint
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteSticker
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteMedal
    ,OID = dbo.tblProjectOffers.id
    ,dbo.tblProjectOffers.odate
    ,ProjectID = dbo.tblProjects.id
    ,dbo.tblProjectOffers.oprice
FROM dbo.tblProjectOffers
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsersVotes
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsers ON dbo.tblUsersVotes.uid = dbo.tblUsers.id
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjects ON dbo.tblUsers.id = dbo.tblProjects.UserID ON dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = dbo.tblProjects.id
WHERE dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = @pid
```

In this select query it shows all records but also has repetitive records. 
For example I want it return just 1 record with 1 UserID.

this is my tables

[image]

sample of user votes

[image: sample of user votes]

tables and result

[image: tables and result]

Comment: Use `distinct` ?

Comment: how with this record?

Comment: Can you provide sample data, expected results, and actual results? As it is now, we can't really help you because we don't know what kind of data you're working with.

Comment: You want to show one row per user? Which of their project offers do you want to show then? Which of their votes? As you join all tables, you get all data. Even multiplied (1 user, 4 votes, 5 offers = 1 x 4 x 5 = 20 rows for that one user). Moreover, you are missing an `ON` clause on `INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsersVotes`. This is invalid SQL. I guess you are using MySQL, which is notorious for not applying to the standard here. This becomes a `CROSS JOIN` thus, joining every offer with every vote.

Comment: And there are two `ON` clauses on `INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjects`, which is also invalid. Each inner join must get one `ON` clause.

Comment: yes i want show one row per user

Comment: plz edit my select query ty

Comment: But what shall this row contain? Let's say a user has sixty votes. You are showing users with their votes, so sixty rows. Which of the votes do you want to pick? Or do you want to show votes at all? And let's say a user has fifty offers. You are showing users with their offers, so fifty rows. Which offer do you want to pick? Or do you want to show offers at all? (And as mentioned you combine all vots with all offers 50x60=300 rows for the user.)

Comment: no user votes will update in 1 row

Comment: "no user votes will update in 1 row"? I don't know what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: i have 1 row for each user and row field values will update if i need

Comment: Show a sample result. Have two users, each with three votes and three project offers. Show the two result rows.

Comment: i add picture from sample of uservotes

Comment: No. No Pictures. Edit your request. Show a user table. Show a votes table. Show the result table. You can use the {} button to format them.

Comment: i add another pic from tables and result

Comment: No. Show *several* votes per user and *several* offers per user. And then show us what the one result row for the user contains. Which of the votes do you pick and why? Which of the offers do you pick and why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    UserID = dbo.tblUsers.id
    ,dbo.tblUsers.nickname
    ,dbo.tblUsers.avatarPic
    ,dbo.tblUsers.userRate
    ,dbo.tblUsers.workedProjects
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.userVotes
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesCount
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesPoint
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteSticker
    ,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteMedal
    ,OID = dbo.tblProjectOffers.id
    ,dbo.tblProjectOffers.odate
    ,ProjectID = dbo.tblProjects.id
    ,dbo.tblProjectOffers.oprice
FROM dbo.tblProjectOffers
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsersVotes
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsers ON dbo.tblUsersVotes.uid = dbo.tblUsers.id
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjects ON dbo.tblUsers.id = dbo.tblProjects.UserID ON dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = dbo.tblProjects.id
WHERE dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = @pid
```

Comment: it return repetitive records

Comment: There might be a problem with your join conditions, verify them. We don't know what is in the tables too, do you have duplicates?

Comment: i add a picture from my tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
SELECT     
   distinct dbo.tblUsers.id
,dbo.tblUsers.nickname
,dbo.tblUsers.avatarPic
,dbo.tblUsers.userRate
,dbo.tblUsers.workedProjects
,dbo.tblUsersVotes.userVotes
,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesCount
,dbo.tblUsersVotes.votesPoint
,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteSticker
,dbo.tblUsersVotes.voteMedal
,dbo.tblProjectOffers.id
,dbo.tblProjectOffers.odate
,dbo.tblProjects.id
,dbo.tblProjectOffers.oprice
FROM dbo.tblProjectOffers
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsersVotes
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUsers ON dbo.tblUsersVotes.uid = dbo.tblUsers.id
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjects ON dbo.tblUsers.id = dbo.tblProjects.UserID ON 
dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = dbo.tblProjects.id
WHERE dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = @pid

FROM    
    dbo.tblProjectOffers 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblUsersVotes 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblUsers ON dbo.tblUsersVotes.uid = dbo.tblUsers.id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblProjects ON dbo.tblUsers.id = dbo.tblProjects.UserID ON dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid = dbo.tblProjects.id
where 
    dbo.tblProjectOffers.pid=@pid
```

Comment: it return repetitive records

Comment: have edited. execute and see the result. if it provides distinct values, there would be non unique values in other columns

Comment: dude i need another fields in my select query but you removed them

Comment: Just select and see, if you are getting distinct values